# How to post data from one model and retrieve to another model of the same app using Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two models which are related by one to many relationship. I want to use the first model called BedNightReturn to post data and another one called BedNightReturnAssessment to calculate the data post and retrieve data. My models are as follows:-

```
class BedNightReturn(models.Model):
    room_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    number_of_rooms = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    price_per_night = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    days_in_month = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'BedNightReturn'
        verbose_name_plural = 'BedNightReturns'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.room_type}'

class BedNightReturnAssessment(models.Model):
    assessment = models.ForeignKey(BedNightReturn, related_name = "assessments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'BedNightReturnAssessment'
        verbose_name_plural = 'BedNightReturnAssessments'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.assessment.room_type}'
    
    @property
    def potential_turnover(self) -> float:
        days_in_month = 30
        return float(days_in_month) * float(self.assessment.number_of_rooms) * float(self.assessment.price_per_night)
    
    @property
    def actual_turnover(self) -> float:
        return float(self.assessment.days_in_month) * float(self.assessment.number_of_rooms) * float(self.assessment.price_per_night)
```

And serializers are as follows:-

```
class BedNightReturnSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BedNightReturn
        fields = (
            'id',
            'room_type',
            'number_of_rooms',
            'price_per_night',
            'days_in_month',
            
        )

class BedNightReturnAssessmentSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    assessment = BedNightReturnSerializer()
    potential_turnover = ReadOnlyField()
    actual_turnover = ReadOnlyField()
    class Meta:
        model = BedNightReturnAssessment
        fields = (
            'id',
            'assessment',
            'potential_turnover',
            'actual_turnover',
        )
```

And views are:-

```
class BedNightReturnViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = BedNightReturn.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BedNightReturnSerializer

class BedNightReturnAssessmentViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = BedNightReturnAssessment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BedNightReturnAssessmentSerializer
```

And urls:-

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers

from bednightlevy.views import (
    BedNightReturnAssessmentViewSet,
    BedNightReturnViewSet,
)

router = routers.DefaultRouter(trailing_slash = False)

router.register('returns', BedNightReturnViewSet, basename="bednight")
router.register('assessments', BedNightReturnAssessmentViewSet, basename='bednight_assessment')

urlpatterns = [
    path('',include(router.urls)),
]
```

The idea is to use */returns* endpoint to post data and */assessments* endpoint to retrieve data (read only).

Comment: so you want to add new data using `/returns` - and for get requests the `/assessments` endpoint?

Then you would want to use the `ReadOnlyModelViewSet` for `BedNightReturnAssessmentViewSet` and create a View with the required mixins for `BedNightReturnViewSet` like mentioned here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#custom-viewset-base-classes

Comment: Yes, I want  to use **/returns** endpoint to post data and the /assessments for retrieving those data which are read-only. Not necessarily to use ModelViewSet

Comment: As stated - use the ViewSets with `ReadOnlyModelViewSet` and for `BedNightReturnViewSet` simply use the create mixin - and if you want to update add the update mixin

Comment: I tried this approach, but it returns an empty list in the nested serializer on BedNightReturnAssessmentSerializer

Comment: Could you test the queryset in the shell?

Answer (score 0):

Use `create` function in `BedNightReturnSerializer` to post your data.

```
class BedNightReturnSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BedNightReturn
        fields = (
            'id',
            'room_type',
            'number_of_rooms',
            'price_per_night',
            'days_in_month',
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        with transaction.atomic():
            BedNightReturn.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Comment: It failed using this approach, it shows empty list in **/assessments** endpoint